# Callback when reminder is displayed in app

Tags: windows-phone-7

I need to know when a reminder from my app in shown while in my app. I thought i would try putting the necessary code in OnNavigatedTo and this would be called when the reminder popup is dismissed but that is not the case.

So i am looking for some way to get a callback in my application when a reminder is shown/dismissed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the RootFrame's unobscured event to check if my reminder had been shown. works great! :)

Answer (score 0):

This is the best I could come up with. `Reminder` and scheduler service don't have mechanism for registering events (which is probably why you asked this question), so I would try something down this route.
Code is self explanatory. You register a timer that would execute at the same time the Reminder is due. However, the timer tick will not be triggered by a thread that will trigger the reminder, it will just execute at the same time. There's a callback you can register and it will call your method.

```
public class MyReminder : Microsoft.Phone.Scheduler.ScheduledNotification
{
    public Action MyCallback { get; set; }

    public void TimerCallback(object state)
    {
        if (MyCallback != null)
        {
            try
            {
                MyCallback();
            }
            catch { }
        }
    }

    public override DateTime ExpirationTime
    {
        get
        {
            return base.ExpirationTime;
        }
        set
        {
            base.ExpirationTime = value;

            System.Threading.Timer timer = new System.Threading.Timer(TimerCallback);
            timer.Change((long)(value - DateTime.Now).TotalMilliseconds, Timeout.Infinite);
        }
    }
}
```